# luaL_dostring() crashes when given script has syntax error

Tags: lua

i try to integrate Lua in a embedded project using GCC on a Cortex-M4. i am able to load and run a Lua script, calling Lua functions from C, calling C functions from Lua. but the C program crashes (HardFault_Handler trap rises) when the given script passed as parameter in luaL_dostring() contains any Lua syntax errors.

here the relevant C code that crashes due to the syntax error in Lua:

```
      //create Lua VM...
      luaVm = lua_newstate(luaAlloc, NULL);

      //load libraries...
      luaopen_base(luaVm);
      luaopen_math(luaVm);
      luaopen_table(luaVm);
      luaopen_string(luaVm);

      //launch script...
      luaL_dostring(luaVm,  "function onTick()\n"
                            "  locaal x = 7\n"  //syntax error
                            "end\n"
                            "\n" );
```

when doing the same with correct Lua syntax, then it works:

```
  luaL_dostring(luaVm,  "function onTick()\n"
                        "  local x = 7\n"  
                        "end\n"
                        "\n" );
```

when debugging and stepping through luaL_dostring(), i can follow the Lua parsing line for line, and when reaching the line with the syntax error, then the C program crashes.

can anybody help? thanks.

---

have disabled `setjmp/longjmp` in Lua source code in the following way:

```
//#define LUAI_THROW(L,c)    longjmp((c)->b, 1) //TODO oli4 orig
//#define LUAI_TRY(L,c,a)    if (setjmp((c)->b) == 0) { a } //TODO oli4 orig

#define LUAI_THROW(L,c)    while(1) //TODO oli4 special
#define LUAI_TRY(L,c,a)    { a }    //TODO oli4 special
```

...so there is no setjmp/longjmp used anymore, but i still have the crash :-(

must have another cause???

Comment: Does your platform support `longjmp`? Does this program crash when run: `error"boom"` ?

Comment: the platform is STM32F4 of ST microelectronics. it seems to support longjmp (let's say: it compiles when using these functions). but in fact, Lua crashes when running error "foo". so it seems longjmp does not work correctly???

Comment: It seems to me `longjmp` is the first thing to look at.

Comment: have made some simple tests with `setjmp/longjmp` jumping out of a function on my platform, and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the problem: it is the sprintf function called on Lua syntax error. in fact, on my platform sprintf seems not support floating point presentation. so i changed luaconf.h the following way, limiting the presentation to integer format.

```
//#define LUA_NUMBER_FMT     "%.14g"
#define LUA_NUMBER_FMT     "%d"
```

Answer (score 0):

> must have another cause???

Yes: you can't use Lua here.

Lua's error handling system is built on a framework of `setjmp/longjump`. You can't just make `LUAI_THROW` and `LUAI_TRY` do *nothing*. That means `lua_error` and all internal error handling stops working. Syntax errors are part of Lua's internal error handling.

If your C compiler doesn't provide proper support for the C standard library, then Lua is simply not going to be functional in that environment. You might try LuaJIT, but I doubt that will be any better.

Comment: I agree. It was not the goal to disable Lua error handling. I had only temporary disabled, to isolate the error cause.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define LUAI_THROW(L,c) c->throwed = true
#define LUAI_TRY(L,c,a) \
    __try { a } __except(filter()) { if ((c)->status == 0 && ((c)->throwed)) (c)->status = -1; }
#define luai_jmpbuf     int  /* dummy variable */
```

```
struct lua_longjmp {
  struct lua_longjmp *previous;
  luai_jmpbuf b;
  volatile int status;  /* error code */
  bool throwed;
};
```

Works as expected even you build without C++ exceptions